# How to replace between existing table rows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to regenerate a table with a new order, the problem i encounter is in the performance,
I Have something like this:

```
<table>
<tr id="row1"></tr>
<tr id="row2"></tr>
<tr id="row3"></tr>
<tr id="row4"></tr>
</table>
```

Obviously my table is much more complex, but what i would like is a solution with good performance for a replacing command
my target table should be something like:

```
   <table id="mainTable">
    <tr id="row3"></tr>
    <tr id="row4"></tr>
    <tr id="row1"></tr>
    <tr id="row2"></tr>
    </table>
```

When I redraw it the performance is bad(for more then 100 lines)
is there any way to just replace the rows between themselves without redrawing it?
Thanks

Comment: In seriousness no one is going to just do this for you. Try yourself, come back when you have an actual specific question to ask

Comment: the first comment isnt helpful, I tried looked and fought it, looking for some new ideas.

Comment: so what exactly is your question? I'm simply trying to point out you haven't asked a question. You've explained what you want then said is it possible. Yes it's possible. If that's not your question then what is it?

Comment: Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I am looking for the way to do it with the best performance

Answer (score 1):

For rearranging them append them using `append()` or `next()`

```js
$table = $('#mainTable');

$table.append($('#row1,#row2', $table));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mainTable">
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row4">
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

The basic sultion is using jquery "after" function , which move the target element after the wanted element ..

```
$("#row1").after("#row4");
```

or if you want to sort the table based on its values , you can use plugins like :  [table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Comment: Did you mean `$("#row1").after($("#row4"));`? Even then it's not going to do what the OP wants.